# Unix use SED in subdirectories without modifying the timestamp of subdirectories

Tags: shell, unix, sed, aix

I am using the following script (in AIX there is no `-i` flag for `sed` and therefore I am using the intermediate temp files) to find and replace a string in a directory and its subdirectories without modifying the timestamp of the files. It works fine on the files. However, it updates the timestamp of the subdirectories. Is there any way to prevent the update of the timestamp of the subdirectories?

```
for f in $(find . -type f -name "*.log")
do
 touch -r $f $f.tmp
 sed "s/str1/str2/" $f > $f.tmp1 && mv $f.tmp1 $f
 touch -r $f.tmp $f
 rm $f.tmp
done
```

Comment: Most system operators won't like this: when something goes wrong, root cause analyses will look when something was changed. I admit logfiles shouldn't be the cause of an incident. You can consider directory names like yyyymmdd_host3.

Comment: The `touch -r` can be done for directories too. When you want to touch a /tmp/dirdate.tmp file before editing files and touching again when files are changed, you should start with finding directories: You don't want to touch a directory with 100 logfiles many times.